# How can I drag & Drop a JPG-File into Scribus?

Tags: nautilus, unity-dash, drag-and-drop, scribus

If I try to drag&drop a JPG (or other Graphic file) from Nautilus via the Unity Dash into Scribus, the Dash symbol’s are "grayed" and only some App's are usable but not Scribus.

How can I make this symbol usable for Drag and Drop?

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to these two bugs [#9452](http://bugs.scribus.net/view.php?id=9452) [#12597](http://bugs.scribus.net/view.php?id=12597). Until this is fixed it may be best to use the new [Picture Browser](http://wiki.scribus.net/canvas/Scribus_1.5.0_Readme#Picture_Browser) found in Scribus 1.5.0 and above.

First, download and install Scribus 1.5.0. A PPA is [available from here](https://launchpad.net/~scribus/+archive/ubuntu/ppa). With it now installed, open Scribus and being a new document. In the Extras menu option click on Picture Browser:
[image]

In the picture browser navigate to the folder containing your images:
[image]

You can now easily click and drag an image from the Picture Browser into you document:
[image]